# Mysqli prepare error: Unknown column 'breta_user_level' in 'field list'

Tags: xenforo

please i need code inser into ... to put it in my php database to fix this echo

```
Mysqli prepare error: Unknown column 'breta_user_level' in 'field list'

Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli->_prepare() in Zend/Db/Statement.php at line 115
Zend_Db_Statement->__construct() in Zend/Db/Adapter/Mysqli.php at line 381
Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli->prepare() in Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php at line 478
Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query() in Brivium/ExtraTrophiesAwarded/Model/exTrophy.php at line 191
Brivium_ExtraTrophiesAwarded_Model_exTrophy->updateLevelForUser() in Brivium/ExtraTrophiesAwarded/Deferred/Trophy.php at line 46
Brivium_ExtraTrophiesAwarded_Deferred_Trophy->execute() in XenForo/Model/Deferred.php at line 295
XenForo_Model_Deferred->runDeferred() in XenForo/Model/Deferred.php at line 429
XenForo_Model_Deferred->_runInternal() in XenForo/Model/Deferred.php at line 374
XenForo_Model_Deferred->run() in XenForo/ControllerAdmin/Tools.php at line 159
XenForo_ControllerAdmin_Tools->actionRunDeferred() in XenForo/FrontController.php at line 351
XenForo_FrontController->dispatch() in XenForo/FrontController.php at line 134
XenForo_FrontController->run() in /home/..../www/forums/admin.php at line 13
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: what codes?
i am asking a code Run SQL query/queries on database to delete this error

Comment: You're executing a Sql query that returns that error, in admin.php line 13. My guess is that the query is wrong or the table your querying into doesn't have the breta_user_level field. But its only a guess...

Comment: thank you very much Elph

Comment: Maybe you can share your solution here, if you solved it. It could be useful for someone with the same problem.